# How to set set keyboard shortcuts in JavaFX from controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I have program which has multiple tabs and every tab has it's own controller. I want to have different keyboard shortcuts on every tab.

However I can't find a way to do this because I need to add EventFilter to Scene but when Controller.initialize() runs, the scene is still null. How to solve this?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
final KeyCombination openDir = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN, KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);

    list.getScene().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
        if (openDir.match(event)) {
            logger.debug("Event match.");
        }
    });
```

Problem is, that `list.getScene()` returns null which is probably because the scene is not yet set when controller initializes.

Comment: Maybe you should have a method `addListener` to the controller that adds the event listener and call that method as soon as the list is part of a scene

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on how to do that? I tried to add listener but there is not onShow() event like in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around I found the following solution. It observes the scene property and when the scene changes it removes the old listener and adds a new one.

```
final KeyCombination openDir = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN, KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);

EventHandler<KeyEvent> eventHandler = event -> {
    if (openDir.match(event)) {
        logger.debug("Event match.");
    }
};

list.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (oldValue != null) {
        oldValue.removeEventFilter(KEY_PRESSED, eventHandler);
    }

    if (newValue != null) {
        newValue.addEventFilter(KEY_PRESSED, eventHandler);
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help you!